# Terminating the contract early (before tenant moves in)

Tags: contract-law, rental-property, residential-lease, rent, netherlands

I live in the UK and am renting out a flat in Netherlands, my tenant gave me  the deposit but the agreement states he has to pay one month in advance. Two weeks have passed since we signed contract but still no money.

**If the tenant hasn't moved into the property yet is there a way to terminate contract on the spot (or some other faster procedure)?

If not, how long do I have to wait to start termination due to non payment, and how do I do this?**

Comment: read your contract, call your lawyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right to end the lease if the tenant hasn't moved into the property yet and hasn't paid the necessary deposit. However, you should ensure that you follow the correct termination procedures by reviewing the contract's terms. You can notify the tenant in writing that the contract is terminated due to nonpayment if the procedure for termination is not specified in the contract.

In the Netherlands, you must follow the eviction procedure if the tenant has already moved in. In most cases, this means giving the tenant notice that they haven't paid. If the tenant still hasn't paid, you can start legal proceedings to evict them. Depending on the particulars of the case, this procedure may take a different amount of time. In order to ensure that you adhere to the correct procedures for terminating the contract and evicting the tenant, you should consult a Dutch lawyer.